# Number of firms per year using dplyr or datatable

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, data-manipulation

Lets say I have data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(City = c("NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA"),
                 YearFrom = c("2001", "2003", "2002", "2006", "2008", "2004", "2005", "2005", "2002"),
                 YearTo = c(NA, "2005", NA, NA, "2009", NA, "2008", NA, NA))
```

where YearFrom is the year when e.g. firm was established and YearTo is year when it was canceled.
If YearTo is NA then it is still working.

I would like to calculate number of firms for every year.

The table should look like this

```
City    |"Year"   |"Count"
"NY"    |2001       1
"NY"    |2002       2
"NY"    |2003       3
"NY"    |2004       3
"NY"    |2005       2
"NY"    |2006       3
"NY"    |2007       3
"NY"    |2008       4
"NY"    |2009       3
"LA"    |2001       0
"LA"    |2002       1
"LA"    |2003       1
"LA"    |2004       2
"LA"    |2005       4
"LA"    |2006       4
"LA"    |2007       4
"LA"    |2008       2
"LA"    |2009       2
```

I would like to solve this by dplyr or datatable package but I can't figure it out how?

Comment: Should the year of cancellation be included or excluded?

Comment: it should be excluded. I think that is the right way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A shorter `tidyverse` solution.

```
# Firsts some data prep
df <- mutate(df,
    YearFrom = as.numeric(as.character(YearFrom)),                     #Fix year coding
    YearTo = as.numeric(as.character(YearTo)),
    YearTo = coalesce(YearTo, max(c(YearFrom, YearTo), na.rm = TRUE))) #Replace NA with max

df %>% 
  mutate(Years = map2(YearFrom, YearTo - 1, `:`)) %>%          #Find all years
  unnest() %>%                                                 #Spread over rows
  count(Years, City) %>%                                       #Count them
  complete(City, Years, fill = list(n = 0))                    #Add in zeros, if needed
```

Comment: Concise and effective. Nice

Comment: All answers are right, but I found your most intuitive. Data table way is faster, but hopefully my dataset is not that big.

Comment: Last line can produce NA for city. Not sure why. When I contraint the Yeares to bi >= 2001 it worked fine.

Comment: @Axeman, I have tried it on  bigger dataset. Also, YaersTo can have the same year as YearFrom, so it is probably better to remove -1 from `mutate(Years = map2(YearFrom, YearTo - 1, `:`)) %>%`.

Answer (score 8):

First, to clean the data...

```
curr_year = as.integer(year(Sys.Date()))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, YearTo := as.integer(as.character(YearTo)) ]
df[, YearFrom := as.integer(as.character(YearFrom)) ]
df[, quasiYearTo := YearTo ]
df[is.na(YearTo), quasiYearTo := curr_year ]
```

Then, a non-equi join:

```
df[CJ(City = City, Year = min(YearFrom):max(YearTo, na.rm=TRUE), unique=TRUE), 
  on=.(City, YearFrom <= Year, quasiYearTo > Year), allow.cartesian = TRUE, 
  .N
, by=.EACHI][, .(City, Year = YearFrom, N)]

    City Year N
 1:   LA 2001 0
 2:   LA 2002 1
 3:   LA 2003 1
 4:   LA 2004 2
 5:   LA 2005 4
 6:   LA 2006 4
 7:   LA 2007 4
 8:   LA 2008 3
 9:   LA 2009 3
10:   NY 2001 1
11:   NY 2002 2
12:   NY 2003 3
13:   NY 2004 3
14:   NY 2005 2
15:   NY 2006 3
16:   NY 2007 3
17:   NY 2008 4
18:   NY 2009 3
```

Comment: Sorry for changing my mind but this is the best answer. I have some issues with other methods!

Answer (score 5):

Here is one answer using `data.table`. The data preparation is at the bottom.

```
# get list of businesses, one obs per year of operation
cityList <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)),
              function(i) df[i, .(City, "Year"=seq(YearFrom, YearTo - 1))])

# combine to a single data.table
dfNew <- rbindlist(cityList)

# get counts
dfNew <- dfNew[, .(Count=.N), by=.(City, Year)]
```

written in one line, this is

```
# get the counts
rbindlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)),
          function(i) df[i, .(City, "Year"=seq(YearFrom, YearTo - 1))]))[, .(Count=.N),
  by=.(City, Year)]
```

Here, `lapply` runs through each row and constructs a data.table with repeated city values as one column and a second column with the years of operation. Here, YearTo is decremented so that it doesn't include the year of closure. Note that in the data preparation, the missing values are set to 2018 so that the current year is included.

`lapply` returns a list of data.tables which is combined into a single data.table via `rbindlist`. This data.table is aggregated to city-year pairs and counts are constructed using `.N`.

these return

```
    City Year Count
 1:   NY 2001     1
 2:   NY 2002     2
 3:   NY 2003     3
 4:   NY 2004     3
 5:   NY 2005     2
 6:   NY 2006     3
 7:   NY 2007     3
  ...
26:   LA 2012     3
27:   LA 2013     3
28:   LA 2014     3
29:   LA 2015     3
30:   LA 2016     3
31:   LA 2017     3
32:   LA 2002     1
33:   LA 2003     1
```

**data**

```
setDT(df)
# convert string years to integers
df[, grep("Year", names(df), value=TRUE) := 
   lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(as.character(x))), .SDcols=grep("Year", names(df))]
# replace NA values with 2018 (to include 2017 in count)
df[is.na(YearTo), YearTo := 2018]
```

Comment: Nice. But why the count in 2005, NY is `3`, rather than `2`?

Comment: Ah. My code includes the year of cancellation. Whether or not that is desirable is worth clarifying.

Comment: @ycw. After consulting with OP, I've adjusted my code to exclude year of closure, but include current year.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  # Change YearFrom and YearTo to numeric
  mutate(YearFrom = as.numeric(as.character(YearFrom)), 
         YearTo = as.numeric(as.character(YearTo))) %>%
  # Replace NA with 2017 in YearTo
  mutate(YearTo = ifelse(is.na(YearTo), 2017, YearTo)) %>%
  # All number in YearTo minus 1 to exclude the year of cancellation
  mutate(YearTo = YearTo - 1) %>%
  # Group by row
  rowwise() %>%
  # Create a tbl for each row, expand the Year column based on YearFrom and YearTo
  do(data_frame(City = .$City, Year = seq(.$YearFrom, .$YearTo, by = 1))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Count the number of each City and Year
  count(City, Year) %>%
  # Rename the column n to Count
  rename(Count = n) %>%
  # Spread the data frame to find the implicity missing value in LA, 2001
  spread(Year, Count) %>%
  # Gather the data frame to account for the missing value in LA, 2001
  gather(Year, Count, - City) %>%
  # Replace NA with 0 in Count
  mutate(Count = ifelse(is.na(Count), 0L, Count)) %>%
  # Arrange the data 
  arrange(desc(City), Year) %>%
  # Filter the data until 2009
  filter(Year <= 2009)
```